# How to make opengl text visible/change color?

Tags: c, opengl

I am doing a mini project on constructive solid geometry using openGL.I am trying to create two windows ,the first one shows my name,college name and other details and the second one will show the solid geometry window.My second screen is working perfectly fine,and i am able to print text on my first screen,but as the background is black in color and text should come in different colors but it's coming in black color only so it's not visible.Below is the code,can anyone check my code and tell me where's the error.

```
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<GL/gl.h>

int isMainScreen=1;
enum {
  CSG_A, CSG_B, CSG_A_OR_B, CSG_A_AND_B, CSG_A_SUB_B, CSG_B_SUB_A
};

/* just draw single object */
void one(void (*a) (void))
{
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  a();
  glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
/* "or" is easy; simply draw both objects with depth buffering on */
void or(void (*a) (void), void (*b) (void))
{
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  a();
  b();
  glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
} 
/* Set stencil buffer to show the part of a (front or back face) that's inside b's volume. Requirements: GL_CULL_FACE enabled, depth func GL_LESS Side effects: depth test, stencil func, stencil op */
void
firstInsideSecond(void (*a) (void), void (*b) (void), GLenum face, GLenum test)
{
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
  glCullFace(face);     /* controls which face of a to use */
  a();                           /* draw a face of a into depth buffer */
  /* use stencil plane to find parts of a in b */
  glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
  glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
  glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0, 0);
  glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_INCR);
  glCullFace(GL_BACK);
  b();                  /* increment the stencil where the front face of b is drawn */
  glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_DECR);
  glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
  b();                  /* decrement the stencil buffer where the back face of b is drawn */
  glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
  glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
  glStencilFunc(test, 0, 1);
  glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glCullFace(face);
  a();                  /* draw the part of a that's in b */
}

void
fixDepth(void (*a) (void))
{
  glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
  glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS);
  a();                  /* draw the front face of a, fixing the depth buffer */
  glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
}
/* "and" two objects together */
void
and(void (*a) (void), void (*b) (void))
{
  firstInsideSecond(a, b, GL_BACK, GL_NOTEQUAL);
  fixDepth(b);
  firstInsideSecond(b, a, GL_BACK, GL_NOTEQUAL);
  glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);  /* reset things */
}
/* subtract b from a */
void
sub(void (*a) (void), void (*b) (void))
{
  firstInsideSecond(a, b, GL_FRONT, GL_NOTEQUAL);
  fixDepth(b);
  firstInsideSecond(b, a, GL_BACK, GL_EQUAL);
  glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);  /* reset things */
}

enum {
  SPHERE = 1, CONE
};

/* Draw a cone */
GLfloat coneX = 0.f, coneY = 0.f, coneZ = 0.f;
void
cone(void)
{
  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(coneX, coneY, coneZ);
  glTranslatef(0.f, 0.f, -30.f);
  glCallList(CONE);
  glPopMatrix();
}

/* Draw a sphere */
GLfloat sphereX = 0.f, sphereY = 0.f, sphereZ = 0.f;
void
sphere(void)
{
  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(sphereX, sphereY, sphereZ);
  glCallList(SPHERE);
  glPopMatrix();
}
int csg_op = CSG_A;

/* add menu callback */
void 
menu(int csgop)
{
  csg_op = csgop;
  glutPostRedisplay();
}

GLfloat viewangle;
void redraw(void)
{
  /* clear stencil each time */
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
  glPushMatrix();
  glRotatef(viewangle, 0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
  switch (csg_op) {
  case CSG_A:    one(cone);
                break;
  case CSG_B:    one(sphere);
                        break;

  case CSG_A_OR_B:    or(cone, sphere);
                    break;
  case CSG_A_AND_B:    and(cone, sphere);
                       break;
  case CSG_A_SUB_B:    sub(cone, sphere);
      break;
  case CSG_B_SUB_A:    sub(sphere, cone);
       break;
  }
  glPopMatrix();
  glutSwapBuffers();
}
/* animate scene by rotating */
enum {
  ANIM_LEFT, ANIM_RIGHT
};
int animDirection = ANIM_LEFT;

void 
anim(void)
{
  if (animDirection == ANIM_LEFT)
    viewangle -= 3.f;
  else
    viewangle += 3.f;
  glutPostRedisplay();
}

/* ARGSUSED1 */
/* special keys, like array and F keys */
void 
special(int key, int x, int y)
{
  switch (key) {
  case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:    glutIdleFunc(anim);
                            animDirection = ANIM_LEFT;
            break;
  case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:    glutIdleFunc(anim);
                      animDirection = ANIM_RIGHT;
                      break;
  case GLUT_KEY_UP:
  case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
                    glutIdleFunc(0);
                    break;
  }
}
/* ARGSUSED1 */
void 
key(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
  switch (key) {
  case 'a': viewangle -= 10.f;
    glutPostRedisplay();
                break;
  case 's':
    viewangle += 10.f;
    glutPostRedisplay();
    break;
    case '\13':
        isMainScreen=1;
        break;
        mydisplay();
    case '\033':
    exit(0);
}
}

int picked_object;
int xpos = 0, ypos = 0;
int newxpos, newypos;
int startx, starty;

void
mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
  if (state == GLUT_UP) {
    picked_object = button;
    xpos += newxpos;
    ypos += newypos;
    newxpos = 0;
    newypos = 0;
  } else {              /* GLUT_DOWN */
    startx = x;
    starty = y;
  }
}
#define DEGTORAD (2 * 3.1415 / 360)
void 
motion(int x, int y)
{
  GLfloat r, objx, objy, objz;

  newxpos = x - startx;
  newypos = starty - y;

  r = (newxpos + xpos) * 50.f / 512.f;
  objx = r * cos(viewangle * DEGTORAD);
  objy = (newypos + ypos) * 50.f / 512.f;
  objz = r * sin(viewangle * DEGTORAD);

  switch (picked_object) {
  case CSG_A:
    coneX = objx;
    coneY = objy;
    coneZ = objz;
    break;
  case CSG_B:
    sphereX = objx;
    sphereY = objy;
    sphereZ = objz;
    break;
  }
  glutPostRedisplay();
}

void drawString1(float x, float y, float z, char * string) {
    char * c;
    glRasterPos3f(x, y, z);
    for (c = string; * c != '\0'; c++) {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15, * c);
    }
}


double vp_width = 512.0; // update by reshape
double vp_height = 512.0; // update by reshape


void frontscreen(void)
{
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( 0, vp_width, vp_height, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0 );
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glColor3f(0.7,0.0,1.0);
    drawString1(200.0,50.0,0.0,"MVJ College of Engineering");
    glColor3f(0.7,0.0,1.0);
    drawString1(165.0,90.0,0.0,"DEPARTMENT OF COMPUTER SCIENCE AND ENGINEERING");
    glColor3f(1.0,0.5,0.6);
    drawString1(185.0,130.0,0.0,"A MINI PROJECT ON:COMPUTER GRAPHICS");
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    drawString1(175.0,170.0,0.0,"PROJECT TITLE:CONSTRUCTIVE SOLID GEOMETRY");
    glColor3f(1,0.5,0);
    drawString1(20,380,0.0,"BY:");
    glColor3f(0.5,0,0.5);
    drawString1(10,410,0.0,"NAME: ANSHU");
    glColor3f(0.5,0,0.5);
    drawString1(10,425,0.0,"USN:1MJ15CS016");
    glColor3f(0.5,0,0.5);
    drawString1(10,440,0.0,"SEC:A");
    glColor3f(0.5,0,0.5);
    drawString1(10,455,0.0,"SEMESTER:VI");
    glColor3f(1,0.5,0);
    drawString1(420,380,0.0,"GUIDE:");
    glColor3f(0.5,0,0.5);
    drawString1(390,400,0.0,"NAME:Ms. Devisivashankari p");
    glColor3f(1,0.1,1);
    drawString1(200,480,0.0,"PRESS ENTER TO START");
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();   // <----- glutSwapBuffers insted of glFlush
    glutPostRedisplay();
}


void mydisplay() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (isMainScreen) {
        frontscreen();  
    } else {
        redraw();
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  static GLfloat lightpos[] =
  {25.f, 50.f, -50.f, 1.f};
  static GLfloat sphere_mat[] =
  {1.f, .5f, 0.f, 1.f};
  static GLfloat cone_mat[] =
  {0.f, .5f, 1.f, 1.f};
  GLUquadricObj *sphere, *cone, *base;

  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitWindowSize(1024,720);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_STENCIL | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);
  (void) glutCreateWindow("csg");
  glutDisplayFunc(frontscreen);
  glutKeyboardFunc(key);
  glutSpecialFunc(special);
  glutMouseFunc(mouse);
  glutMotionFunc(motion);

  glutCreateMenu(menu);
  glutAddMenuEntry("A only", CSG_A);
  glutAddMenuEntry("B only", CSG_B);
  glutAddMenuEntry("A or B", CSG_A_OR_B);
  glutAddMenuEntry("A and B", CSG_A_AND_B);
  glutAddMenuEntry("A sub B", CSG_A_SUB_B);
  glutAddMenuEntry("B sub A", CSG_B_SUB_A);
  glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);

  glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
  glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightpos);
  glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_TRUE);

  /* make display lists for sphere and cone; for efficiency */

  glNewList(SPHERE, GL_COMPILE);
  sphere = gluNewQuadric();
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE,sphere_mat);
  gluSphere(sphere, 20.f, 64, 64);
  gluDeleteQuadric(sphere);
  glEndList();
  glNewList(CONE, GL_COMPILE);
  cone = gluNewQuadric();
  base = gluNewQuadric();
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, cone_mat);
  gluQuadricOrientation(base, GLU_INSIDE);
  gluDisk(base, 0., 15., 64, 1);
  gluCylinder(cone, 15., 0., 60., 64, 64);
  gluDeleteQuadric(cone);
  gluDeleteQuadric(base);
  glEndList();
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glOrtho(-50., 50., -50., 50., -50., 50.);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;             /* ANSI C requires main to return int. */
}
```

frontscreen method is the first screen which should come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i am able to print text on my first screen,but as the background is black in color and text should come in different colors but it's coming in black color only so it's not visible

When lighting ([`GL_LIGHTING`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml)) is enabled, then the color is taken from the material parameters  ([`glMaterial`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMaterial.xml)).

If you still want to use the current color, the you have to enable [`GL_COLOR_MATERIAL`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml)
and to set the color material paramters ([`glColorMaterial`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColorMaterial.xml)):

```
glEnable( GL_COLOR_MATERIAL );
glColorMaterial( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE );
```

See also [Basic OpenGL Lighting](https://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/opengl_lighting.html).

---

I recommend to disable lighting when you draw the text:

```
void frontscreen(void)
{
    glDisable( GL_LIGHTING );

    .....
}
```

But to enable lighting when you draw the scene:

```
void redraw(void)
{
    glEnable( GL_LIGHTING );

    .....
}
```

Comment: I have added a case in my keyboard function where if i press enter it should go the next window,but it isn't working,can you tell me where is the error?

Comment: Enter key is working now but when the second window is coming,the objects are not of same color and even the functions a only,b only etc are not working.

Comment: Color for enter key is pink,so when the window is getting changed all the objects are in pink color only.